# Bash script to run C++ binary N times and output average to file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a C++ program that I've compiled, called `code.cpp`.

The binary file outputted is `./code`.

The code outputs several lines of text, with the last line representing the wall time in seconds. So, for example:

```
<some_text>
<more_text>
...
<still_more_text>
0.0009072
```

For any given set of runtime flags, I would like to create a simple Bash script to run `./code` with the requested flags 10 times, and then print a single line to a text file. The file should be named exactly what `./code` was called as, so for example:

`./code -g 12 -v 4 -m -t`

Would produce a text file called `./code -g 12 -v 4 -m -t.txt`, containing a single line representing the average of ten runs.

Comment: Ok, you wrote, above, that you "would like to create a simple Bash script" to do something. Now, what is your specific question?

Comment: I'm asking for the script, top to bottom.

Comment: This is not really a `C++` question tbh.

Comment: We do not write programs or scripts for other people, here. Stackoverflow.com is for questions and answers. "Write a program or a script for me" is not a question, it is a request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working solution I arrived at using Bash and bc:

```
#!/bin/bash

sum=0.0
c_command=$1
suffix=".txt"
f_name="${c_command} ${suffix}"

for n in {1..10};
do 
    output=$($c_command)
    read -ra arr -d '' <<<"$output" 
    value=${arr[-1]}
    sum=$(bc <<< "scale=10; $sum+$value")
done

avg=$(bc <<< "scale=10; $sum/10")
echo $avg > "${c_command}.txt"
```

Where the binary is called with run-time params as an argument to the script:

```
./script.sh "./code -g 12 -v 4 -m -t"
```